# ubuntu 15.10 update broke USB ports

Tags: usb, update-manager, hardware, 15.10

in ubuntu 15.10 my system added some updates using the automatic software updater. it prompted me to restart my system and after I did my USB ports are no longer recognized.

I just switched over to Linux and do not know how to tell if it was the updates that broke my system or not. I also do not know how to roll back the updates in case it was the update... any help would be great thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did that upgrade include the kernel? If that's the case, try running the older kernel version from the grub boot screen.

Reboot your PC and when you see `grub` choose `advanced options for Ubuntu` and select the previous kernel version from the list, if you can't see `grub` at boot, press the left <kbd>Shift</kbd> key after the bios screen.

You should also look at the output of the terminal command `dmesg` for any hints at what may be going wrong.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, while this is the correct answer, how about explaining how to change the kernel for the OP ? It is encouraged that you add detail to the answer for new and inexperienced users, please see http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: What is the OP?

Comment: It is a stack exchange term meaning `original post` or `poster`.

Comment: That's not quite what I mean, it is good to have the information in the answer rather thann a link, I will show you, it will still be your answer, I will just make an edit.

Comment: Is there a way I can see a list of the most recent updates? I was not really paying too much attention when I accepted the update to begin with so I am unsure if it updated the kernel or not... Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If you can get to the grub menu (which may require holding the left Shift key while booting) and go to "Advanced options", you'll see a list of the installed kernels. Or you can run dpkg-log-summary to see which packages were installed/uninstalled/upgraded recently.